# w3m Lookup, Special Characters

Tags: w3m

If I search for "c#" or anything with special characters, they somehow get removed.

Not sure which part of this removes the "#";)

```
(defun w3m-lookup-first-clipboard-item ()
  "Look up the current word's definition in a browser.
If a region is active (a phrase), lookup that phrase."
 (interactive)
 (let (myword myurl)
   (setq myword (current-kill 0))
  (setq myword (replace-regexp-in-string " " "%20" myword))
  (setq myurl (concat "https://www.google.com/search?q=" myword))
  ;;(browse-url myurl)
  (w3m-browse-url myurl)
   ))
```

Comment: Please consider clarifying what you mean by "special character". Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not sure which part of this removes the "#";)

Nothing in your posted code removes the "#". Remember that a "#" specifies an anchor in a url. `https://www.google.com/search?q=c#` is a url with a null anchor, and so is getting reduced to `https://www.google.com/search?q=c`. Instead of using `replace-regexp-in-string` on your search term try [`url-hexify-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/url/URI-Encoding.html#index-url_002dhexify_002dstring-1) instead. This will "escape" non-reserved characters (the space character, some symbols, etc.) as percent-delimited hex values.

```lisp
(defun w3m-loopup-first-clipboard-item ()
  "Look up the current word's definition in a browser.
If a region is active (a phrase), lookup that phrase."
  (interactive)
  (let (myword myurl)
    (setq myword (current-kill 0))
    (setq myword (url-hexify-string myword))
    (setq myurl (concat "https://www.google.com/search?q=" myword))
    ;;(browse-url myurl)
    (w3m-browse-url myurl)
    ))
```